# Iterate two data frame whitout same lenght

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate on two dataframes that do not have the same size in order to output the list of users, with their information, who are leaving the company and who are still active.

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['PAUL','LAURE','DAVID','MAT'],
'MATRICULE':['AP','MP','ND','AD'],
'ACTIF':['YES','YES','YES','NO']}
```

```py
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['MIKE','DAVID','MAT']}
```

```py
while i in df2.index:
    for j in df1.index:
        user_leave=[]
        if df2['Name'][i] == df1['Name'][j] and df1.ACTIF[j]=='Yes':
            user_leave=df1.iloc[i]
        else :
            j=j+1
            i=i+1
print(user_leave)
```

The result should be like this :

```
Name     Matricule
David    ND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better option than iterating over DataFrame, you can filter your first DataFrame according to the second DataFrame values and select the desired columns.

See the following code:

```
df1[(df1.Name.isin(df2.Name)) & (df1.ACTIF=='YES')][['Name', 'MATRICULE']]
```